# How to use fosuserbundle in symfony2 using annotations as router?

Tags: symfony, annotations, yaml

I am a beginner of Symfony2, and I just met some problems.

I have 2 bundles, both use annotations as router, and they share one database of orm called mydb. And when I was going to use FOSUserBundle, I put these code in the app/coonfig/route.yml just like the documentation says:

```
# app/config/routing.yml

fos_user_security: resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile: resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml" prefix: /profile

fos_user_register: resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml" prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting: resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml" prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password: resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml" prefix: /profile
```

And when I use command php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force, the command told me "The table with name 'mydb.apply' already exists", apply is a table of the database.

So, why would these happen? I searched on the web and found that maybe this is because both bundles share the same database. A better solution is that put these code in bundle/Resources/config/route.yml instead of app/config/route.yml and just add these code in app/config/route.yml:

```
FirstBundle:
    resource: "@FirstBundle/Resources/config/route.yml"
```

Unfortunally I have chosen annotations as my routers, how should I handle the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## About your Error

> And when I use command php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force,
>   the command told me "The table with name 'mydb.apply' already exists",
>   apply is a table of the database.

the command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

is used to update table in database.

if symfony tell you that 'mydb.apply' already exists

you probably two entity with:

```
@ORM\Entity()
@ORM\Table(name="apply")
```

## About your Routing

Your application needs only one database

You can have (must have) several bundle in your application.

In each bundle, you can use xml or annotation

You might use annotation for your personal bundle

But FOSUserBundle use xml configuration (because it's a best practice)

Follow carefully the FOSUserBundle documentation and everything will be ok ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you please be more specific? I truly have two entity with name="apply", but they are in different bundle. My key problem is: How to make those code of fosuserbundle just inside one of the bundle?

Comment: A bundle is just a part of your application, you must use different table name. Because all entity goes in the same database

Comment: the proof is you have only one parameter.yml (database infos)